# Dynamically update forwarding IP in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, dynamic-dns

As the usual disclaimer - I've looked for a solution for quite some time but didn't find any working solution yet.

**Goal:** Create a Dynamic DNS solution to access my home network without third-party services.

**Set-up:** Internet server running nginx with available domains, local network with router, automatically assigned a new IP each day by the ISP.

**Achieved so far:** I managed to use nginx as a reverse proxy to forward requests to `https://dyn.mydomain.tld` to `https://my.current.ip.address` using a `server` directive corresponding to

```
server {
    443 ssl http2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate  /etc/letsencrypt/live/dyn.mydomain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dyn.mydomain.tld/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://my.current.ip.address;
    }
}
```

This successfully and transparently redirected the request to the local router's web interface.

**Problem:** However, of course I need this to work with my dynamic IP address. I can tell my router to call an arbitrary URL, passing the new IP address whenever it changes, so what I seem to need is a URL on my server that will update the IP to which nginx redirects requests. What I'm looking for is a solution that will do that with as little performance and (more importantly) security implications.

**Thoughts:**
What I thought first is having that IP in a file that is read by nginx, but I have read this should give quite bad performance (if it is at all possible to make a variable read from a file in the nginx config).

Another idea would be to have a script update the IP address somewhere and have nginx reloaded to "statically" load the value. However, that would mean I'd have to give a publicly reachable script/URL root privileges, at least to restart nginx and perhaps rewrite a file - which seems like something I wouldn't want to do?

**Question** (concise): is there a way to provide nginx with a dynamic value for IP forwarding that can be updated by executing a script upon an HTTPS request initiated by the router?

**Aside:** The implementation listed as "achieved so far" presents the Lets Encrypt certificate installed on the server to the browser, while the (self-signed) certificate of the browser isn't used anymore (when accessing the router's configuration page directly through its current IP or through a third-party Dynamic DNS service the browser complains about the self-signed certificate). While this looks like a convenience progress, isn't this a security problem as the router's identity might not be checked properly?

Comment: Wouldn't the simple solution be to make the receiving script simply write the current IP value to a plain file and leave the task of handling everything else to a second (privileged) automated script that would parse that file?

Comment: Basically yes, but two questions: a) how is the privileged script notified about the need to update (I would prefer an "event" based system over, say, a cron job) b) is there a way to change the rewrite-to IP without reloading/restarting nginx?

Comment: I would think doing some simple directory monitoring would be sufficient. If your IP file exists, execute the needed actions then delete/move that trigger file. You could also be more subtle and watch for file modifications. A tool such as `inotify` or similar variants might work well for this. Regarding Nginx, I don't know there is. Other servers behave similarly as well (Apache, BIND for DNS). That said, these programs all have methods of reloading config files with as little interruption as possible. Nginx in particular tries to gracefully shutdown processes to avoid perceptable downtime.

Comment: You seem likely to be aware of this, but Nginx has the `reload` command to do "hot reloads" (ostensibly zero downtime) of the config files - - https://serverfault.com/q/378581/210623

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a promising approach. A "backend" script with inotify could be run with the privilege to reload nginx. I'll report back when I had the chance to try it.

Comment: Your welcome. I will be glad to hear how it works out.