# Use nginx to invoke a script

Tags: bash, nginx, url-rewriting

I want to use a specific URL to invoke a maintenance script (related to [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/1251366/dynamically-update-forwarding-ip-in-nginx)). I don't want to have to manage this maintenance script as a service/server because it will usually only be run once a day.

So what I would like to know is how I can rewrite a URL in nginx to a) invoke a (Linux) shell script and b) pass it the request's payload. (I'm not sure yet if the script has to send back any response).

Although this seems like a natural question I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I read the other question, and this seems like a convoluted approach.  What I do is have my internal server monitor its own public address, then update a DNS entry in an external server.  Not a dyndns type thing, just using BIND and nsupdate.  No need for a second nginx externally and proxying everything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'd need more hints to look into this on my own. What I have is a toplevel domain pointing to my remote server where nginx is listening. In the nginx config I configure subdomains, and what I want is to have one of these subdomains point to the changing IP of my router. I don't know how I could update an external DNS entry from my router.

Comment: Sure - do you run the DNS server for your domain yourself?

Comment: No, I can only edit records through a web interface provided by the ISP.

Comment: But can you run it yourself on the server that has nginx on it?

Comment: Actually this is a point where I'm out of knowledge. I have root access to my server, so I can probably run any service/server I want. But I don't know how the external world would get to know about a DNS running on my IP.

Comment: Sure - well this is taking your idea in an entirely different direction, so it might not be what you want.  But basically, you have a registrar for your domain, and that is where you state where the name servers are for the domain.  They can be your own.

Comment: What I *want* is creating a private dynamic DNS redirection in order not to rely on third-party providers. So that would be in line with what I want to achieve (although not anymore with this SU question). In the web interface for my domains there are two NS entries which I can't edit. But I can *add* NS entries. So do I get this right that I would have to install and configure bind and then add an NS record for the subdomain I want to redirect, have that point to my server's IP and expect this to propagate to the global DNS network?

Comment: Yeah exactly.  Note that DNS doesn't really "propagate", it is just what techs have told customer to explain why their DNS updates aren't immediate.  A fresh DNS request will always get the latest record from the authoritative DNS server for a zone, but that query comes with a TTL value, which tells everything participating in that query how long they can consider that record accurate for.  Once the TTL expires, they must go back to the authority and get a new one but until then, they can cache the record so they don't need ask again.

Comment: I use a cron job for this type of thing

Comment: Tim, you mean a cron job that runs really often (probably every minute), will notice when a file has been written and only then performs the larger configuration?`